# Error compiling VHDL in VLSI

Tags: vhdl, cpu, vlsi

I am creating a CPU in my VLSI, starting with a register:

```
library ieee;   
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package types is
    type BYTE is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic;
end types;

-- Have to use one file because of Electric's compiler
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use work.types.all;

entity reg8 is
    port (
        clock   : in std_logic;
        inc     : in std_logic;
        dec     : in std_logic;
        store   : in std_logic;
        input   : in BYTE;
        output  : out BYTE
    );
end reg8;

architecture rtl of reg8 is
    signal state : BYTE;
begin
    tick : process(clock) is
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clock)) then
            if inc = '1' then
                state(0) <= not state(0);
                state(1) <= state(0) xor state(1);
                state(2) <= (state(0) and state(1)) xor state(2);
                state(3) <= (state(0) and state(1) and state(2)) xor state(3);
                state(4) <= (state(0) and state(1) and state(2) and state(3)) xor state(4);
                state(5) <= (state(0) and state(1) and state(2) and state(3) and state(4)) xor state(5);
                state(6) <= (state(0) and state(1) and state(2) and state(3) and state(4) and state(5)) xor state(6);
                state(7) <= (state(0) and state(1) and state(2) and state(3) and state(4) and state(5) and state(6)) xor state(7);
            elsif dec = '1' then
                state(0) <= not state(0);
                state(1) <= state(0) xnor state(1);
                state(2) <= (state(0) or state(1)) xnor state(2);
                state(3) <= (state(0) or state(1) or state(2)) xnor state(3);
                state(4) <= (state(0) or state(1) or state(2) or state(3)) xnor state(4);
                state(5) <= (state(0) or state(1) or state(2) or state(3) or state(4)) xnor state(5);
                state(6) <= (state(0) or state(1) or state(2) or state(3) or state(4) or state(5)) xnor state(6);
                state(7) <= (state(0) or state(1) or state(2) or state(3) or state(4) or state(5) or state(6)) xnor state(7);
            elsif store = '1' then
                state <= input;
            end if;
        end if;
        output <= state;
    end process tick;
end architecture rtl;
```

and I am getting weird errors that don't happen with my syntax checker, such as why I need a "PORT" keyword for a process.

Full log from Electric:

```
Compiling VHDL in cell 'reg8{vhdl}' ...ERROR on line 25, Expecting keyword PORT:
tick : process(clock) is 
              ^
ERROR on line 25, Expecting keyword MAP:
tick : process(clock) is 
              ^
ERROR on line 25, Expecting a semicolon:
tick : process(clock) is 
                      ^
ERROR on line 26, Invalid ARCHITECTURAL statement:
begin 
^
ERROR on line 27, Expecting keyword END:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
^
ERROR on line 27, Expecting a semicolon:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
  ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
   ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
              ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
               ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
                    ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
                     ^
ERROR on line 27, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if(rising_edge(clock)) then 
                       ^
ERROR on line 28, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if inc = 11 then 
^
ERROR on line 28, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if inc = 11 then 
   ^
ERROR on line 28, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if inc = 11 then 
       ^
ERROR on line 28, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if inc = 11 then 
         ^
ERROR on line 28, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
if inc = 11 then 
            ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
     ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
      ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
       ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
         ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
            ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
                ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
                     ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
                      ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
                       ^
ERROR on line 29, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(0) <= not state(0); 
                        ^
ERROR on line 30, No entry keyword - entity, architectural, behavioral:
state(1) <= state(0) xor state(1); 
^
TOO MANY ERRORS...PRINTING NO MORE
```

I am using Electric VLSI, available at http://www.staticfreesoft.com/index.html in case anyone wants to try this out.

Comment: with the missing `use work.types.all;` clause added, this analyses correctly in ghdl so it may be a tools issue. Does the tool require package, entity and architecture in separate files or something?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Electric's Silicon Compiler doesn't have an obvious way to do multiple files, but I would if I could.

Comment: [11.5.10 Silicon Compiler](http://www.rulabinsky.com/cavd/text/chap11-5.html) ***The QUISC silicon compiler accepts a structural VHDL description of a circuit and a standard cell library. It compiles the VHDL to a netlist, places the standard cells, and routes them to create layout for the VHDL*** [Kostiuk]. The reference is a Master's Thesis from 1987. Your VHDL isn't a structural description. A cell would have a single entity and instantiate cell library primitives.

Comment: It seems this is "Electric" not a generic VHDL compiler. It only supports a certain subset and structure. I.e. what you are trying to do will probably not work. You will need to switch to a "better"(and paid) ASIC synthesis tool, like Synopsys tools.

Comment: You should not create new array type of `std_logic`. This type will be imcompatible to `std_logic_vector`. You should declare a *constrained subtype* of `std_logic_vector` as follows: `subtype BYTE is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);`

Comment: @user1155120 Thank you for clarifying. I have only started to learn VHDL, and so I don't know many specifics. Do you have any suggestions as to how to make this a structural description?

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you for letting me know. I wish there was a free one, as I am a student.

Comment: @Paebbels Thank you! I will do that. I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Doesn't your university have some university-program with a specific vendor? Usually the place where you produce your ASIC will have a preference for a specific tool. You should talk to them.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not a university student. I'm a middle-schooler who is self-taught in computer engineering from Java to C to now VHDL. I also don't have a way to produce ASICs yet. I am planning on for now using the silicon compiler to create a map of transistors to guide me in making a design on breadboards.

Comment: @Rdrpenguin Wow, interesting idea! However, realizing a circuit made by an ASIC compiler with conventional transistors will likely require A LOT of transistors. And I might not work, as some design programs require very specific transistor properties. It would be much easier just to use a (C)PLD or some logic gate chips (7400-series) to realize your design.

Comment: @JHBonarius Also, could you post your answer as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked, so:

It seems this is "Electric" not a generic VHDL compiler. It only supports a certain subset and structure. I.e. what you are trying to do will probably not work. You will need to switch to a "better"(and paid) ASIC synthesis tool, like Synopsys tools.

Realizing a circuit made by an ASIC compiler using conventional transistors will likely require A LOT of transistors. And it might not even work as intended, as ASIC design programs mostly require very specific transistor properties. It would be much easier just to use a (C)PLD or some logic gate chips (7400-series) to realize your design.